# Modifying Google Search Results Page

Tags: javascript, dom-events, greasemonkey

I have written a greasemonkey script which will do `GM_xmlhttpRequest`
to the next 2 pages of the google results page.. i.e. if my current
page is 1 then my script will do `GM_xmlhttpRequest` to page no 2 and
3..

Now my script will extract out all the urls from these 3 pages and
will reorder them

For that I have done:

```
unsafeWindow.addEventListener('load',Reorder,true);

function Reorder()
{
alert("onload fired")
..........
..........
// some code overhere to collect all the urls into an array
// and to reorder the urls in the array
```

Now I inject these urls into my reference pages i.e. I keep a
reference to the nodes where I am supposed to append these urls as
childNodes.. and along with that I modify the links to page no. 2 and
3(at the bottom of results page) so that now they'll point to my these newly dynamically generated
pages. For that I modify the `onclick` attribute of these links that'll
open a new window in the current window itself and will write the
modified responseXML object to the newly created window.

Now everything is working awesome i.e. url
extraction, reordering, creating new window, writing the `responseXML`
object ..

But the problem is that when my these modified links are clicked and
my newly generated window replaces the parent window it doesn't give the alert of "onload fired"
...infact it doesn't stop loading i.e. it displays the desired
content but is never fully loaded since status bar doesn't shows
"done" in fact it shows "waiting for clients1.google.com"...

So does anyone knows what exactly is going wrong over here.. is it due
to some script running on google search page that is somehow
synchronised with the contents of the page...

Basically for those who do not know how greasemonkey will work.....my code is just removing all the anchor tags that contain url and inserting similar anchor tags with different urls...the question in nutshell is that i am just making a new window and doing document.write(this newly created html page)...and other than the urls I am not changing anything....
so basically are the scripts somehow synchronized with the urls present on the page or does it really matter to the scripts what data is contained within as long as the body contains the same DOM tree.

Please people whatever you know or have idea about it.. please tell me...

i need to finish this thing quickly..

Comment: You haven't posted enough code for us to really tell what's going on.  Post the full code, or at least enough to fully duplicate the problem.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for not posting sufficient code but since i am a newbie to stackoverflow i just didn't know what all to post. I was lucky enough to get the desired answer. Many many thanks to people like you who help others in their hour of need without even knowing them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `document.write` to write content into a new page, you need to use `document.close()` to tell the browser that you're done - until then, the browser thinks there is more content to come and continues to display the loading icon.

Comment: Thank you very much casablanca for your spontaneous and perfect answer. You have done a great favour to me.